# Change button colour on click

Tags: android

So I have started using Android Studio to code and am running into a little difficulty. I found that there is no need to set an onclick listener if you implement android:onclick in the xml file. However, I am unsure how to correctly implement the code in the java activity to mesh with the xml files. What I am seeking to do is take two buttons and upon clicking them, have the buttons change to a different color. This is my first post so excuse anything I might have missed.

I added in the output from the java log file once i tried to run the script again. I am unsure what it means that it found an error inflating the class. I have searched documentation on this but if anyone has any ideas on this. The only thing i could think of was that this button class isn't actually created anywhere, but I honestly dont' know and am grasping at straws :)

**content main.xml**

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
        android:onClick="myMethod"/
```

>

**MainActivity.java**

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    }
```

**Button_Custom**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/red"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/blue"></item>
</selector>
```

**red.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <shape android:shape = "rectangle" android:color = "#FF0000"></shape>
</selector>
```

**Error output**

```
Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class Button
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                                   Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class Button
```

Comment: You can add android:background="@drawable/button_custom"  in your xml file.

Comment: Thanks. Any ideas on troubleshooting a java view.inflate error that i am getting. It references a binary xml file, but isn't specific which xml it is talking about.

Comment: copy  Button button = (Button) findViewById(button); to oncreate() method.

Comment: Is that the oncreate options or the oncreate bundle saved instance state?

Comment: in @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {}

Comment: Gotcha. thanks for the help, was just curious though why this would work because Button is an android widget and as such, would that throw an error saying can't convert to int which is what findViewbyId asks for?

Comment: Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mybutton);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not use a method for that! Simply set your custom background for any button you want. Your button in your layout should look like:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_custom"        
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="78dp"
    />
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Comment: @D.Shadow If the answer was helpful, please click the checkmark under the like button to indicate so.